# custom form validation class in CI isn't being called in live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

In CI projects, I have added custom form validation library 'My_Form_validation' under application > libraries > My_Form_validation.php. In autoload.php I have added the library as

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'form_validation', 'slug');
```

In Controller,

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules($this->category->rules);
```

In Model,

```
public $rules =
        array(
            array(
                'field' => 'name',
                'label' => 'Category Name',
                'rules' => 'trim|required|unique[tbl_category.name.'.$id.']',
            )
        );
```

Now, the problem is the 'unique' form validation gets called in local server and is working fine but in live server the custom form validation library isn't called. Where have I done wrong ? Any help/suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with `$this->form_validation->set_rules(implode(',', $this->category->rules[0]));`.

Comment: @Tpojka No, the option isn't working.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Any error? Log? Apache log? PHP/CI log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said it was working in local but not in live server.It may be due to case sensitivity of your file name  "My_Form_validation". Please be sure that  you named it correctly . 
 Can you  renamed your file name to "MY_Form_validation"  and try it once?

Answer (score 0):

Check your config.php

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

And change your form validation file name

`My_Form_validation` to `MY_Form_validation`

and also change your library

Comment: whenever I change as per you say ... the page remains blank.No error message .. nothing, just a blank page

Comment: are get 500 internet server error in browse console ?

Comment: no , i am not getting any error. No error in console as well.